# fetch all the users with specific attribute

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

Hey everybody Im new with node and mongo hope for your help with it.
I defined a user schema with mongoose:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({


local            : {
    email        : String,
    password     : String,
    name         : String
},
facebook         : {
    id           : String,
    email        : String,
    token        : String,
    firstName    : String,
    familyName   : String
},
google           : {
    id           : String,
    email        : String,
    token        : String,
    firstName    : String,
    familyName   : String
}});
```

Im tring to fetch all the users (from local google and facebook) with specific email.
How do I write it ? 
I tried something like:

```
var User = require('./models/user');
app.get('/api/user/:email',function(req,res){
    User.findOne({'email':req.params.email},function(err,user){
       res.json(user);
    })
});
```

How do I fix it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

to your schema file.

Then try the following:

```
var User = require('./models/user');
app.get('/api/user/:email',function(req,res){
    User.findOne({"local.email": req.params.email}, function(err,user){
        res.json(user);
    });
});
```

Or for all three:

```
var User = require('./models/user');
app.get('/api/user/:email',function(req,res){
    User.findOne({$or: [
        {"local.email": req.params.email},
        {"facebook.email": req.params.email},
        {"google.email": req.params.email}
    ]}, function(err,user){
        res.json(user);
    });
});
```

Comment: but you will get only from local user ? but what if the mail is in facebook/google ?

Comment: You did not specify that in your schema which is something you might wanna do

Comment: I added it to my post